# 301 redirect in htaccess not working as expected

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to add a simple 301 redirect to a website's htaccess, but no redirection is occurring, nor am I encountering any errors--can anyone shed some light?  The redirect would redirect people visiting an old blog post to a new page:

- old blog post:  https://www.horizonhomes-samui.com/horizon-homes-construction/
- new page:  https://www.horizonhomes-samui.com/construction/

The redirect code I'm using is:

```
Redirect 301 /horizon-homes-construction/ https://www.horizonhomes-samui.com/construction/
```

**Possibly Relevant Info**

- My site is a Wordpress site.
- I also tried adding a "RewriteEngine On" line to the top, but that did not resolve the issue.
- The htaccess file I'm editing is located in my WordPress root directory (along with wp-content, wp-admin, index.php, etc).
- The instructions I'm following for adding the 301 redirect are from [this guide](http://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/beginners-guide-to-creating-redirects-in-wordpress/).

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to place this code on top of your htaccess file? Or on the bottom. Your code is fine -my test it on my server worked as expected.

Comment: @AdrianLambertz yes I did try inserting at the top of htaccess, but was met with the same results.  Thanks for your test.  That should give sufficient reason to escalate this to my server admin for troubleshooting.  I'll post back if/when a resolution is determines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of my server admin, I ascertained why this 301 redirect was not working.  It is because my site is on an Nginx server, so any redirects added to htaccess will not be read by the server.  My server admin was able to add the redirects properly.

Answer (score 0):

When you don't have a lot of control over the server, which is the case for a lot of wordpress sites, a plugin is better than trying to update the .htaccess file.

I am sure there are a lot of good plugins that do this. This one has worked for us.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/

Comment: Thanks for that.  I might try that.  But for now, and partially for my own edification, I'd like to see how far I can get with the non-plugin solution.  If need be, I can contact the server admin for specific questions/issues.